# nodejs latest version on my pc is not the latest

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

i was going to start use reactjs when but i had this :

```
create-react-app myapp
You are running Node 9.11.2.
Create React App requires Node 14 or higher. 
Please update your version of Node.
```

i tried to update my node js by runing :

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
libllvm6.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

My pc is 32 bit extensa 5635z
my os is lubuntu

any help please ?

Comment: Install a version from "NodeSource" as "Der Henning" mentioned

Answer (score 0):

To install the desired version of nodejs you can use the [NodeSource Node.js Binary Distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions).

For Node.js v17.x:

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: i tried this and allways when i do sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
i get the same result Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4).

Comment: Did you try the manual installation https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debmanual ? Especially removing old ppas?

Comment: i tired it know and it is all the same problem 
this is my problem : (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4) it stack allways here !!

Comment: @TRicheT Have you uninstalled every node version before you tried the nodesource method?